# Solving for Bananas

Tags: python, random, quiz

This code creates a problem for the user to solve (very simple problem) it will then check if the user has got it right and will say so.

```
import random
import time
def mathsquestion():

    attempts=2
    bananas1 = random.randrange(1,40)
    bananas2 = random.randrange(30,70)
    print('lucy has', bananas1,' bananas and tracy has', bananas2,' if both of them put their bananas together and split them evenly')
    question = float(input('how many bananas do each of them get?'))


    if question == (bananas1+bananas2)/2:
        print ('correct')
        restart=input('want to try again')
        if restart == ('yes'):
            mathsquestion()

    else:
        print('wrong')
        attempts-=1
        print('you have',attempts,'attempts remaining')
        question2 = float(input('how many bananas do each of them get?'))
        if question2 == (bananas1+bananas2)/2:
            print('yay finally')
            restart=input('want to try again')
            if restart == ('yes'):
                mathsquestion()

        else:
            print('wrong')
        attempts-=1
        print('you have',attempts,'attempts remaining')
        print('shutting down')

    if attempts == 0:
        time.sleep(3)
        quit()

mathsquestion()
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### General Feedback

The good thing is that it is quite clear what your code does. You have for the most part clear variable names and not too much clutter. However I would change `bananas1` to `lucys_bananas` and `bananas2` to `tracys_bananas`.

It seems you are familiar with another programming language. Python has a style guide [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which explains in excruciating detail how to structure your code. I whole heartily recommend skimming through it and follow it.

You write `attempts = 3` however according to PEP 8 it is commended to use `CAPITALIZED_WITH_UNDERSCORES` for constants, `UpperCamelCase` for class names, and `lowercase_separated_by_underscores` for other names.

### Error handling Logic

The first thing that came to mind was

```
question = float(input('how many bananas do each of them get?'))
```

I guess you thought that it was a good idea to make question into a float since `(bananas1+bananas2)/2` creates a float. The idea is good but what happens if I guess something that is not a float? Your whole program crashes! A good way to avoid this is to catch the error before it happens

```
question = input('how many bananas do each of them get?')
try:
    question = float(question)
except:
    print('Error, number of bananas must be an integer')
    continue
```

With how your code is currently setup this does not quite work. However we can make a few more changes. Getting half number of bananas, and having to work with floats when bananas is integers is in my opinion a tad strange. However it is possible to make sure that the number of bananas always is evenly divisible. If Lucy has a odd number, then Tracy has to have a odd number of bananas. Similarly if Lucy has an even number, then Tracy has to have an even number of bananas. Since \$(2L+1)+(2T+1)=2(T+L+1)\$ and \$2L+2T=2(T+L)\$. This can be coded as follows.

```
    lucy_bananas = get_bananas(1, 40)
    even_lucy_bananas = lucy_bananas % 2
    tracy_bananas = get_bananas(30+even_lucy_bananas, 70+even_lucy_bananas, 2)
```

To switch behaviour we can put the creation of the random variables into a new function. Se the revised code below

The next part is strange and not very pythonic.

```
if attempts == 0:
    time.sleep(3)
    quit()
```

What is the purpose of `time.sleep(3)`? Also `quit()` is something which you should never have to use. The standard is `return` however a better solution is to wrap the entire function in a while loop. That way it can terminate once `attempts` reaches zero.

## Further tips and changes

What your function does is clear however it would be much clearer if you split it into smaller parts. A good practice is that each function has a single purpose, as it stands your main function does too many things.

1. Unnecessary import the `time` is not neccecary
2. You do not need to import the entire `random` libary, you are only using a single function.
3. You should use the [`if __name__ == "__main__":`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) module in your answer.
4. Duplication of code you write `question2 = float(input('how many bananas do each of them get?'))` more than once.
5. The above is not really a question is it? A better name would be `answer`
6. Error handling, you convert `answer` to a `float`, what if this causes an error? You have no way to detect this.
7. `mathsquestion()` should not call itself, you should leave this to a `main` function.
8. The creation on random variables should be put into a seperate function
9. Clear variable names are good, but you should also have included a short explenation of what your code does. This is done by using [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)
10. The printing could be improved by using [pythons awesome formating options](https://pyformat.info/)

I have improved the first few points in the code below. I will leave the rest to you.

```
from random import randrange

MAX_ATTEMPTS = 3
LUCY_MIN_BANANA = 1
LUCY_MAX_BANANA = 40
STACY_MIN_BANANA = 30
STACY_MAX_BANANA = 70
EVEN_BANANAS = True

def get_bananas():
    lucy_bananas = randrange(LUCY_MIN_BANANA, LUCY_MAX_BANANA)
    if EVEN_BANANAS:
        offset = lucy_bananas % 2
        step = 2
    else:
        offset = 0
        step = 1      
    tracy_bananas = randrange(STACY_MIN_BANANA+offset, STACY_MAX_BANANA-offset, step)
    return lucy_bananas, tracy_bananas


def mathsquestion():

    lucy_bananas, tracy_bananas = get_bananas()
    bananas_evenly_divided = float(lucy_bananas+tracy_bananas)/2

    print('lucy has', lucy_bananas, ' bananas and tracy has', tracy_bananas,
          ' if both of them put their bananas together and split them evenly')
    print('how many bananas do each of them get?')

    attempts = MAX_ATTEMPTS
    while attempts > 0:

        answer = input('answer: ')
        try:
            answer = float(answer)
        except:
            print('Error, the number of bananas must be an integer')
            continue

        if answer == bananas_evenly_divided:
            return True
        print('attempts remaining: ', attempts-1)
        attempts -= 1
    return False


def main():
    want_to_play = True
    while want_to_play:
        guess_correct = mathsquestion()
        if guess_correct == True:
            print('Congratulations!)')
        else:
            print('Better luck next time!')
        restart = input('want to try again? [y/n]: ').lower()
        if restart not in ['yes', 'y']:
            want_to_play = False


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Comment: Please, do not suggest using bare `except`. Always specify the exception you're willing to handle. Here you want `except ValueError`.

Comment: thankyou for the suggestions will use them and rewrite my code. I am very new to programming and have just used my general knowledge of what I know to create this.